# How to load Hard Coded Pages with CMS values using PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, content-management-system

Let me explain the scenario first.

I have built a cms in which I load every page on one page like this.

> http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?page=about

Here "about" is a slug of the page I create from the Cms.
So the sql query fetch the record using the slug & retrieve the content of the page & print it on index.php

Now the next thing I have done is, I have done URL rewriting in .htaccess file like below

> Options +FollowSymlinks RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*(images/|.js|.css).*$ [NC]
>   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?page=$1

So now I can use this kind of URLs on my site for same "about" page

> http://www.mywebsite.com/about

Now the Question is, these all pages are simply content based, but how should I maintain Dynamic pages.
E.g. I have a page for Member Registration as signup.php

I want to assign all the title, heading, meta desc, meta keywords from CMS to this page but also want to load this page using

> http://www.mywebsite.com/signup.php
>
> & not like
>
> http://www.mywebsite.com/signup

What kind of logic should I apply to load the page as signup.php & also fetch the CMS values ?
One solution I have in mind is, we should put one more field in CMS as "Code File :" & enter signup.php over there. But still I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Add another rewrite condition which forces it to not redirect to index.php:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
```